# Bedeutung von "jemandem den Kalender führen"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Aus der *Süddeutschen Zeitung*:

> Norbert Blüm hat noch seinen Terminkalender aus jenen Tagen, als die Geschichte Fahrt aufnahm. Ein klassischer Papierkalender mit einer Spalte für jeden Tag. **Wer immer ihm diesen Kalender geführt hat**, er oder sie hat die Weltgeschichte auch erst einmal ein bisschen wirken lassen, so wie Matthias Sammer, der Fußballer es tat.

Was bedeutet es, jemandem den Kalender zu führen? Ich habe im Wörterbuch sowohl [Kalender](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/kalender) als auch [führen](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/fuhren) nachgeschlagen, bin mir aber noch immer nicht sicher. Heißt es, dass jemand die Einträge in Blüms Kalender schreibt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das Verb ***etwas (=Akk.) führen*** bedeutet in diesem Zusammenhang, dass ein Schriftstück, in diesem Fall ein Kalender, organisiert und immer wieder aktualisiert wird. Beispielsweise kann man sagen:

> (ein) Tagebuch führen
>   einen Kalender führen
>   ein Haushaltsbuch führen
>   Buch führen
>   ...

Im Englischen würde man das am ehesten mit *to keep* übersetzen (*keep a diary, a calendar, the accounts, etc.*).

Das Dativpronomen ***ihm*** bedeutet in der Tat, dass er den Kalender nicht selbstständig führt, sondern irgendeine andere Person diese Aufgabe *für ihn* übernimmt. Diese Dativ-Verwendung nennt man auch [dativus commodi](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dativ#dativus_commodi_bzw._incommodi).